# Cannot revert to the other parent of a merge commit

Tags: git, merge

I have a faulty merge commit that I want to revert to. Specifically, I want to revert to the 2nd parent of the merge commit.

```
$ git revert -m 2 <merge-commit>
```

Nothing happens when I try to revert instead this is what I get in return:

```
$ git revert -m 2 <merge-commit>
On branch dev
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/dev'

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Reverting to the first parent works so I was under the assumption that reverting to the other parent should work just as well. How do I successfully revert to the second parent of my merge commit?

Comment: Did you hard-reset to the merge commit before reverting to the 2nd parent?

Comment: @ElpieKay I have not. I actually have one other faulty commit before the merge commit that I reverted and pushed.

Answer (score 0):

Are there any differences between between the merge commit you mention, and its 2nd child ?

```
git diff <merge-commit>^2 <merge-commit>
```